# how to display excel file in listBox in vb6

Tags: excel, vb6

i tried to display excel file in vb6, and i tried the following code to displaying it:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
       Dim xlsApp As Excel.Application 
       Set xlsTemp = New Excel.Application
       wbk = xlsTemp.Workbooks.Open = "C:\MANGO\Test.xls" 'xls file path
       List1.AddItem (wbk) 'add data wbk
End Sub
```

but, it returned the 449 error

so, what should i do to make it work like a charm.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add a `Workbook object` to a list, this is inconsistent.

You can add a `String` so try something like:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
       Dim xlsApp As Excel.Application 
       Set xlsTemp = New Excel.Application
       wbk = xlsTemp.Workbooks.Open = "C:\MANGO\Test.xls" 'xls file path
       List1.AddItem (wbk.Name) 'add data wbk
End Sub
```

using the `Name` property of the Workbook object.

Btw, you could have found this by yourself using Excel included help :

- select `AddItem`
- press <kbd>F1</kbd>
- read the help file telling you wich arguments you should give, especially which **type** (in this case, `AddItem` expected a `String` for the `Text` argument

Comment: i don't have msdn library for vb6 :(